# Change order of integration 4

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int_{-1}^1dy\int_{0}^{1-y^2}f(x,y)dx $$
i need to change the order of integration so first of all i need to do a picture. After making a picture i get something like that.

$$ \int_{-\sqrt{-x-1}}^{\sqrt{-x-1}}dx\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dy $$

Is that right? Thanks for help ;)

Comment: Do you mean $1 - x^2$ instead of $1 - y^2$ in the first one?

Comment: As hinted by the last comment, you might want to check whether the integral at the start of the question is copied correctly. If you can upload your picture somewhere, it might help. (I don't think you have enough reputation to make the picture visible in the question, but you can add a link to the picture, and someone might then change it to an embedded image.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really dislike that way of writing a double integral!  Surely the function to be integrated must be **between** the "$\int$" and the "dx" so should be either $\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_0^{1- y^2} f(x,y)dx\right) dy$ or
$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1- y^2} f(x,y)dx dy$.

In any case, y goes from -1 to 1 and, for every y, x goes from 0 to $1- y^2$.  In order to cover that same region in the other order, x must go from 0 to the vertex of the parabola, x= 1.  And, for every x, y must go from the lower part of the parabola up to the upper part.  The parabola is given by $x= 1- y^2$ so that $y^2= 1- x$ and then $y= \pm\sqrt{1- x}$.  That is, y goes from $-\sqrt{1- x}$ to $\sqrt{1- x}$.

The integral is $\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1- x}}^{\sqrt{1- x}} f(x,y) dy dx$.

Comment: Yeah your way of writing it  is 5 times more clear for me. I did horrible mistakes in case of my form. Thanks for answer :) It give me easier look for that topic!

Comment: @user247327 I agree that it is confusing, but it is fairly ordinary notation in physics.  It highlights the fact that $\int\mathrm{d}x$ is an operator acting on a space of integrable functions, in the same way that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is an operator on a space of differentiable functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, in my opinion you are not correct. It should be
$$\int_{y=-1}^1dy\int_{x=0}^{1-y^2}f(x,y)dx=
\int_{x=0}^1dx\int_{y=-\sqrt{1-x}}^{\sqrt{1-x}}f(x,y)dy.$$